# all filters item when select two or more checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I just want to make a filter with checkbox array using jquery and javascript. It works fine when only one checkbox is selected but when I select two or more checkboxes it doesn't show all the divs. Could you please help me to find my mistake. I want to filter through the filter array. The name of our array is FlyList

```js
let FlyList = [{
    "id": "1",
    "Type_ticket": "systemi",
    "Airline": "ata",
    "fly_time": "04:00",
    "Class_type": "Commercial",
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "Type_ticket": "charteri",
    "Airline": "Air-Tour",
    "fly_time": "08:00",
    "Class_type": "Commercial",
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "flight_number": "950",
    "Type_ticket": "systemi",
    "Airline": "taban",
    "fly_time": "11:00",
    "Class_type": "Commercial",
    "price": "30000",
    "time": "11:00",
    "capacity": "5",
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "Type_ticket": "systemi",
    "Airline": "mahhan",
    "fly_time": "14:00",
    "Class_type": "Economical",
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "Type_ticket": "charteri",
    "Airline": "kaspian",
    "fly_time": "17:00",
    "Class_type": "Commercial",
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "Type_ticket": "charteri",
    "Airline": "kaspian",
    "fly_time": "21:00",
    "Class_type": "Economical",
  },
];

function customFilter(list, field, value) {

  let fill = list.filter(item => {
    if (typeof(filter) === 'Object') {
      value.foreach(val => {
        if (item[field] === value) {
          return item[field] === value

        }
      });
    }
    return item[field] === value
  });
  console.log(fill);
}

let filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.customCheck');
filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let filterTypeElement = findFilterTypeElement(e.target);
  if (filterTypeElement) {
    let field = filterTypeElement.getAttribute('data-field');
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log(field, val);
    customFilter(FlyList, field, val);
  }
}));

function getParents(el, parentSelector /* optional */ ) {

  // If no parentSelector defined will bubble up all the way to *document*
  if (parentSelector === undefined) {
    parentSelector = document;
  }

  var parents = [];
  var p = el.parentNode;

  while (p && (p !== parentSelector || p.parentNode)) {
    var o = p;
    parents.push(o);
    p = o.parentNode;
  }
  parents.push(parentSelector); // Push that parentSelector you wanted to stop at

  return parents;
}

function findFilterTypeElement(el) {
  var result = null;
  var parents = getParents(el);

  parents.forEach((item) => {
    if (hasClass(item, 'filter_type') && result == null) {
      result = item;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

function hasClass(element, className) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') > -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="filters">
  <div class="collapse show" id="collapseFilters">
    <div class="filter_type" data-field="Type_ticket">
      <h6>Type of ticket
        <div class="switcher float-left ">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="selectall">
            all Type of ticket
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck w-100 " id="filter-check">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="systemi" class="individual"> systemi
            <div class="indicator"></div>

          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck w-100" id="filter-check2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="charteri" class="individual"> charteri
            <div class="indicator"></div>

          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_type airlineSelection" data-field="Airline">
      <h6>airline
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
            all airline
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input type="checkbox" value="ata" name="inlineRadioOptions"> آتا
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Air-Tour" name="inlineRadioOptions"> ایرتور
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="taban" name="inlineRadioOptions"> تابان
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="frans" name="inlineRadioOptions"> frans
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="emirates" name="inlineRadioOptions"> emirates
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="dubai" name="inlineRadioOptions"> dubai
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_type" data-field="Class_type">
      <h6>Class_type
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
            all Class_type
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Economical" name="inlineRadioOptions"> economical
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Commercial" name="inlineRadioOptions"> commercial
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_type" data-field="fly_time">
      <h6>fly_time
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
            all fly_time
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input type="checkbox" value="04:00" name="inlineRadioOptions">
            04:00-08:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="08:00" name="inlineRadioOptions">
            08:00-11:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="11:00" name="inlineRadioOptions">
            11:00-14:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="14:00" name="inlineRadioOptions">
            14:00-17:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="17:00" name="inlineRadioOptions">
            17:00-21:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="21:00" name="inlineRadioOptions">
            21:00-24:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To get all the filters. And our box when a filter was selected as a group. to be displayed. I use this method.

```js
FilterItems = [
    {"Type_ticket" : "[]"},
    {"Airliner" : "[]"},
    {"fly_time" : "[]"},
    {"Class_type" : "[]"}
];
```

Thank you for your answer. But it gives us three errors.

[image]

Comment: What are the filter rules? Show any match or show only all matches? Also not clear how you use `FilterItems`

Comment: Please use stack snippets only if you have full code that run in browser, otherwise use `{}` button or indent with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors, 1 you don't return new array from customFilter and 2 you don't pass it to next checkbox. So you need to save the FlyList in temp variable name and filter it and update it with value from function.

```
function customFilter(list, field, value){

    return list.filter(item=> {
            if(typeof(filter) === 'Object'){
                value.foreach(val => {
                    if (item[field] === value){
                        return item[field] === value

                    }
                });
            }
            return item[field] === value
        });
}
function checkedInputs() {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll('.customCheck')].filter((c) => c.checked);
}


let filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.customCheck');

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox =>checkbox.addEventListener('change' , (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    // you need each checkbox on each change
    var checkboxes = checkedInputs();
    var filteredList = FlyList;
    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
       let filterTypeElement = findFilterTypeElement(checkbox);
       if (filterTypeElement) {
         let field = filterTypeElement.getAttribute('data-field');
         let val = e.target.value;
         console.log(field,val);
         filteredList = customFilter(filteredList, field , val);
       }
    });
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it gives us three errors.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: querySelector is not defined
    at checkedInputs (functions.js:1013)
    at HTMLLabelElement.checkbox.addEventListener (functions.js:1022)

Comment: @سعیدمرادی Ah, sorry it should be `document.querySelector`, my bad.

Comment: functions.js:1008 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at checkedInputs (functions.js:1008)
    at HTMLLabelElement.checkbox.addEventListener (functions.js:1017)

Comment: @سعیدمرادی from what I've understand from your code, you have parent with class `filter_type` that have checkbox as child. Is that true? also it should be `querySelectorAll` like in your code and `filter` instead of `map`. If you still have error from querySelectorAll just remove `.filter_type` from the query so the selector is the same as in your code that works, if course if you don't have that error in your original code.